# python: I want to sort a list, which is in a dict

Tags: python

In the following code test1 works, test2 does not.

I think the copy doesn't copy to where it's supposed to. 
Is this a namespace problem? Can you explain to me whats going on - or even better, how to make test 2 work (items in the must_be_sorted array, so that I can make a general purpose function)?

```
import copy


## test 1

items = {"gi":[{"urc":2}, {"urc":1}]}

must_be_sorted = [{"l":"gi", "key":"urc"}]

for ls in must_be_sorted:
    items[ls["l"]] = sorted(items[ls["l"]], key=lambda k: k[ls["key"]])

for u in items[must_be_sorted[0]["l"]]:
  print "a:", u["urc"],    
print

for u in items["gi"]:
  print "b:", u["urc"],
print

## test 2

items = {"gi":[{"urc":2}, {"urc":1}]}

must_be_sorted = [{"l":items["gi"], "key":"urc"}]

for ls in must_be_sorted:
    #ls["l"] = sorted(ls["l"], key=lambda k: k[ls["key"]])
    ls["l"] = copy.copy(sorted(ls["l"], key=lambda k: k[ls["key"]]))
    for u in ls["l"]:
      print "c:", u["urc"],    
print

for u in items["gi"]:
  print "d:", u["urc"],    


'''
a: 1 a: 2
b: 1 b: 2
c: 1 c: 2
d: 2 d: 1
'''
```

Comment: why do you need to copy the result? (also in `test 2`, you are not affecting `items`, you are modifying directly `ls`) (-> close as typo)

Comment: Yes, I am only changing ls - may be I worked too much today.

Comment: ... but I still don't manage to change items, when it is given as in test2. May this is really a stupid question, but how should I do it? I want to write a function, which gets must_be_sorted as parameter and does the change.

Comment: shouldn't that line start with `items[ls["l"]]` in test 2? (still don't see what is the use of a shallow copy here)

Comment: ok, the use of the copy is only one of my tests. I tried some things even exec and so on. In test 2 the ls["l"] is items["gi"], isn't it? At least, when I print ls["l"] I get [{'urc': 2}, {'urc': 1}]. So ls["l"] and items["gi"] are two variable names for the same thing. So I should be able to change it using ls["l"] or items["gi"].    -- Or am I totaly wrong and should go to holidays?

Comment: this is getting confused, but I think the point is if you change `ls['l']`, it does not change the content of `items['gi']` (becquse you are reaffecting the variable)

Comment: @njzk2 Thank you for your patience. I got it now. And I admit that my questioning was confusing. Will try to close (never did it before).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ls["l"] and items["gi"] in test 2 point to different objects. I can use locals()["items"] to get to the same object.